# Can a mongodb insert contain an expression?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to insert a mongodb document with a field `id` equal to the string representation of `_id` (historic reasons, don't ask). Short of specifying my own _id, is there any way to do it in one call?

This inserts a field that's a literal "$_id".

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
...
user = { "name": "ccc", "address": "Highway 37", "id": "$_id" }
result = db.users.insert_one(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that MongoDB assigns the `_id` after the query gets evaluated so you can try something like that:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

...
user = { "name": "ccc", "address": "Highway 37"}
result = db.users.insert_one(user)
# get the _id to insert it again
_id = result.inserted_id
db.users.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)},{"$set": {"id": _id}})
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the answer to my question is no. No expressions, no way to insert with one line without specifying my own _id. Is that right?

There are other use cases of using expressions. Just to be clear, there is no way to have mogodb calculate anything for me at all during insert? No creation date, no lookup for example?

Comment: @IrinaRapoport When you perform an insert using an object, that object will automatically be assigned the _id, so you would know _id value only at the run time but not before the insert, that's what makes your question a bit tricky and hence the need for the update

Comment: And if it was a field other than _id?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the _id yourself instead of letting mongo do it

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

_id = ObjectId()
user = {"_id": _id, "name": "ccc", "address": "Highway 37", "id": _id }
result = db.users.insert_one(user)
```